# Small native cross-platform GUI framework for C++

Tags: c++, frameworks, cross-platform, native

I wrote a small program with Boost in c++. It works fine and so I want to give it a graphical interface so that it is easier to use.
In order to do so, I am looking for small cross-platform framework which provides native look and feel. Windows and Linux support would be enough, currently i do not need os x...

I used wxWidgets for some other project, but it was a pain to set everything up and ship this big library with the software.
But I was really amazed by the use of real native controls.
In order to keep the program small I also tried fltk, but it has an awful look.

I just need an simple framework without network support or other gimmicks.

So my question: Is there any framework out there which fits all the requirements? Or if not, which frameworks fits at least some of these needs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All basic controls; buttons textbox inputfield radiobutton and if possible progressbar

Comment: Cross platform GUI framework != small.

Comment: So, not trees, grids, charts -- will you ever need them?

Comment: Maybe someday a tree but no grids and definitely no charts

Comment: You can take Qt without bringing *everything* in. For the most part, you really would only need `QtCore` and `QtGui`. It's also pretty easy to deliver to end users.

Comment: I also would go with Qt. It also looks the best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When it has the word "framework" in its name it's almost never small.

Anyway, graphical frameworks/libraries tend to be big, cause they need to handle a lot of stuff.

Qt is probably the best straightforward library for cross-platform GUI, but it definitely doesn't constitute a "small framework". On the other hand, on Linux systems, Qt will be most likely already installed. Plus it definitely pays for its size.

Answer (score 4):

wxwidgets is fairly small as far as gui toolkits go.

And it's cross platform

http://www.wxwidgets.org/

You have mentioned it, but as far as cross platform toolkits go it's one of the smallest I've seen.

The only other suggestion I have is that you could wrap your code up into a C library and link that into another language.  e.g. Use .NET on windows and mono for linux or even a java based app (although they don't always look very native to the platform).  Then use your library from there.

Comment: He mentions wxWidgets in the question. Though I agree that it's probably smaller than Qt, it is probably the best he's going to get given his parameters.

Answer (score 2):

[Ultimate++](http://www.ultimatepp.org/) might contain what you need. (Although they make it sound in the FAQ as if their library is really big, it doesn't seem that bad to me.)

Comment: Looks quite interesting. Thank you for this hint, I will take a close look at it. Do you know whether this framework is easy to set up?

Comment: it is under windows, don't know about linux, seems to depend on the distribution.

Answer (score 2):

don't forget to check [juce](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php) as well

Comment: Seems to be an option. Does it emulate the controls? I was not able to find it out... But thank you as well:)

Comment: Yes, juce uses its on controls and draws everything from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Qt works amazingly, but is not very small. I've found there is a genuine lack of "small" cross-platform GUIs. You either might try to just abstract your GUI with #ifdefs all over the place, or use Qt/wx.

Comment: The massive use of #ifdefs is absolutely not that I want to do. But thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be small, just write the GUI twice -- once in MFC and then in X.  Your GUI sounds simple enough.  Build up your own small abstraction that is just what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is a long list of both active and dead cross-platform C++ UI libraries here: https://philippegroarke.com/posts/2018/c++_ui_solutions/
Some of them are small and have a native look.

Answer (score -1):

Like others mentioned you cannot mix the "cross platform" and small in size in the same sentence.

More work, smaller in size:
One solution I can suggest is to use native python binding for the UI portion. Since you are already using boost, it should be fairly trivial to have Boost.Python communicate between C++ space and python space. You already have python on Linux and its a 20-40MB package on Windows (can't remember how big the latest release is). But here you will have to use win32 binding on windows and gtk/qt bindings on linux, so more work. Nah, too much work to maintain, scratch this.

Moderate work, smaller in size but with non-native controls:
You can try to get clutter or freeglut to get your UI work done but I personally haven't used them so I don't know if they provide full native looks for your apps. But they are small in size compared to wx or qt.

Less work, bigger in size:
Use WxWidgets if you are already comfortable with it, otherwise I recommend Qt.

You can also have a look at some of the other offerings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits

Clutter: http://www.clutter-project.org/about
FreeGLUT: http://freeglut.sourceforge.net

Comment: Please tell me how you mean it with the use of Clutter. I understood that it is a framework for e.g. games like SFML. But I could not find the possibility of creating real controls in the docs.

Comment: Like I said, I personally haven't used clutter but you probably won't get the native controls using clutter. You will most likely have to re-design your UI to something similar to apps in tablets.

Answer (score -2):

ever heard of QT ???

http://qt.nokia.com/products/

i think it should fits all your your needs

Comment: Of course ;) But I just got to know it as a powerful but also really large library comparable to wxWidgets. Am I wrong?